# Moving the i2c and SPI physical pin location on Beaglebone Black

Tags: beagleboneblack

I have found descriptions on how to use the GPIO on Beaglebone, but what I am looking for is how to re-assign the pinout of P8 and P9.

I want to assign the SPI to a different pin set to what it already is.  I wish to group the PWM's in one area, (as they are currently spread all over the board) and I wish to assign the I2C bus to a different pinset.  any ideas?

Thanks Phil

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible.  Each pin may have multiple modes that you can enable but that set of modes is fixed for each pin and you can't move them around arbitrarily.